# adding frequency elt to a list of list for each elt in python

Tags: list, python-3.x

I have a list of elements (list) wich if formatted like this:

3823,La Canebiere,LOCATION

3949,La Canebiere,LOCATION

3959,Phocaeans,LOCATION

3990,Paris,LOCATION

323,Paris,LOCATION

3222,Paris,LOCATION

Some location names (elt[1]) may appear two or more times in the list, but with a different elt[0](id number). What I'm trying to achieve is adding frequency of elt[1] in the list, adding this frequency to each elt and discarding noun (elt[1]) duplicates. For my example the new tab would be :

3823,La Canebiere,LOCATION, 2

3959,Phocaeans,LOCATION,1

3990,Paris,LOCATION,3

I tried a count method and dictionnary for counting frequency but I don't know how to create the new list that would maintain the original list (without duplicates) plus the frequency. I'm using python 3. Thank  you in advance if you can help !

Comment: hello, welcome to stackoverflow. You said you can make a dictionary, are you basically asking how to turn dictionary into list?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use to count frequency of a term with a dictionnary, but it seems useless here as I would like to add the frequency of the term to each element of my list, maintaing my original list without duplicates? I'm not sure of the method I must use here I'm quite newbie to Python...